# How to parse a string to key value pair using regex?

Tags: json, regex, parsing, fluentd

What is the best way to parse the string into key value pair using regex?

**Sample input:**

```
application="fre" category="MessagingEvent" messagingEventType="MessageReceived"
```

**Expected output:**

```
application         "fre"
Category            "MessagingEvent"
messagingEventType  "MessageReceived"
```

**We already tried the following regex and its working.**

```
application=(?<application>(...)*) *category=(?<Category>\S*) *messagingEventType=(?<messagingEventType>\S*)
```

But we want a generic regex which will parse the sample input to the expected output as key value pair?

Any idea or solution will be helpful.

Comment: Does it _have_ to be a regex?

Comment: Yes actually we need it in fluentd to parse and send it to elastic search as Json.

Comment: Ah OK, I was quite pleased with `Hash[str.scan(/(\S+)="(\S+)"/)]` before the comment / edits, but guess it's not to purpose :)

Comment: Thanks for reply @SRack . If we integrate with ruby script. We will use your snippet of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
input = 'application="fre" category="MessagingEvent" messagingEventType="MessageReceived"'

puts input.
       scan(/(\w+)="([^"]+)"/). # scan for KV-pairs
       map{ |k, v| %Q|#{k.ljust(30,' ')}"#{v}"| }. # adjust as you requested 
       join($/) # join with platform-dependent line delimiters

#⇒ application                   "fre"
#  category                      "MessagingEvent"
#  messagingEventType            "MessageReceived"
```

Comment: Dear mudasobwa, Thanks for the prompt response. As a ruby code this works fine. Will try whether I will be able to integrate ruby code in fluentd parser. Regex will be much helpful. Regards,Raj

Comment: @rajkumar21 why would you tag a question [tag:ruby] if a ruby answer was not necessarily acceptable?

Comment: @engineersmnky Actually fluentd is a ruby application. For  now I have a way to integrate with Regex, so I’m waiting for regex. And In parallel we are trying to find a way integrate ruby script . If successful I will mark this as right answer.

Comment: Regex: `/((\w+)="([^"]+)"\s+)+/`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex, it can be done by spliting and storing the string in hash like below:

```
input = 'application="fre" category="MessagingEvent" messagingEventType="MessageReceived"'
res = {}
input.split.each { |str| a,b = str.split('='); res[a] = b}
puts res
==> {"application"=>"\"fre\"", "category"=>"\"MessagingEvent\"", "messagingEventType"=>"\"MessageReceived\""}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we just look at the problem statement, we can solve it many ways but we need it integrate with fluentd parser. If we are able to integrate using ruby then I will try this option and mark it as right answer.